# Return mapped data from parking_lot::RwLock

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow

My struct has a vector inside a `parking_lot::RwLock`, and one member function has to return a guarded element from that vector:

```
use parking_lot::*;

struct S {
    v: RwLock<Vec<String>>,
}

impl S {
    fn f(&self, i: usize) -> MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, Option<&String>> {
        RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
    }
}
```

(this is the simplified core of the problem, not the real code)

The code passes type checks, but I get lifetime errors for `f`.
Is there a way to modify the code so that it is sound *and* passes the borrow checker?

The error is:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:9:66
   |
9  |         RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
   |                                                                  ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 9:45...
  --> src/lib.rs:9:45
   |
9  |         RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:9:57
   |
9  |         RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 8:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:8:5
   |
8  | /     fn f(&self, i: usize) -> MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, Option<&String>> {
9  | |         RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
10 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:9:9
   |
9  |         RwLockReadGuard::map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| &unlocked.get(i))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected  `lock_api::rwlock::MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, _, std::option::Option<&std::string::String>>`
              found  `lock_api::rwlock::MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, _, std::option::Option<&std::string::String>>`
```

Comment: _"Is there a way to tell Rust that the code is safe?"_  -- Of course, but what makes you think it is safe?

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't be sound. `&unlocked.get(i)` takes the reference of a temporary `Option<_>`, and `MappedRwLockReadGuard` would store a pointer to that temporary value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `RwLockReadGuard::try_map()` and to change the return type from `MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, Option<&_>>` to `Option<MappedRwLockReadGuard<'a, _>>`:

```
impl S {
    fn f(&self, i: usize) -> Option<MappedRwLockReadGuard<'_, String>> {
        RwLockReadGuard::try_map(self.v.read(), |unlocked| unlocked.get(i)).ok()
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason people might downvote this answer is because the object you use is provided by the lock api crate: https://docs.rs/lock_api/latest/lock_api/struct.RwLockReadGuard.html 

which is not something usable in std::snyc

Comment: The question *explicitly* asks about `parking_lot`, so I don't see why the answer not being usable for `std::sync` is a reason to downvote it.

Comment: ah you are right! Although I did not downvote it so I don't know why was it then.